# How does C assert that this struct is not equal to zero?

Tags: c#, c, assert, zero

I am trying to understand (with my C# background) how does the following assert work for `msf_s`:

https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/libcdio/blob/master/lib/driver/sector.c#L66

```
cdio_assert (msf != 0);
```

https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/libcdio/blob/master/lib/driver/cdio_assert.h#L50

```
#define cdio_assert(expr) \
 assert(expr)
```

https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/libcdio/blob/master/include/cdio/types.h#L217

```
  PRAGMA_BEGIN_PACKED
  struct msf_s {
    uint8_t m, s, f; /* BCD encoded! */
  } GNUC_PACKED;
  PRAGMA_END_PACKED
```

It is used in the following [snippet](https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/libcdio/blob/master/lib/driver/sector.c#L135):

```
lba_t
cdio_msf_to_lba (const msf_t *msf)
{
  uint32_t lba = 0;

  cdio_assert (msf != 0);

  lba = cdio_from_bcd8 (msf->m);
  lba *= CDIO_CD_SECS_PER_MIN;

  lba += cdio_from_bcd8 (msf->s);
  lba *= CDIO_CD_FRAMES_PER_SEC;

  lba += cdio_from_bcd8 (msf->f);

  return lba;
}
```

Basically, I need to replicate the same behavior but in C#.

**Question:**

Does `cdio_assert` sums up each field of `msf_s` and assert they're not equal to zero ?

Comment: How can a struct be zero?

Comment: [`msf` is a pointer](https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/libcdio/blob/141d1a03c62cec757d79d447777b956ea662fbed/lib/driver/sector.c#L62). The equivalent in C# is checking whether a variable of reference type is `null`

Comment: In the code you linked, `msf` is a pointer - which can (of course) be 'zero' (null).

Comment: The question is not self-contained. Please edit the code so that it has a full [mre].

Comment: You guys are absolutely right, now that I've edited the question and pasted relevant code, I realise my mistake, I should have read better :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the code you linked:

```c
void
cdio_lsn_to_msf (lsn_t lsn, msf_t *msf) // <===== here
{
  int m, s, f;

  cdio_assert (msf != 0);

  // ...
```

You'll see that the variable `msf` is **a pointer** to a variable of type `msf_t`. While it does not make sense for a structure to be `0`, a pointer can very well be `0`, aka `NULL`. That line is just making sure that `msf` is valid before using it. Most of the times this is done with an `if`, but this function apparently expects the value to be valid.

The equivalent in C# would be to assert `msf != null`.

Answer (score 1):

... and to elaborate on Marco's point, the code (IMHO) *should use `NULL`, not zero.*

If you see "zero," you automatically assume "the variable being tested is a number."  If you see `NULL`, you automatically know that it's a pointer.  Although the two ways of saying it might be equivalent and although both might be valid, the confusion that led to this question being asked could have been avoided by writing source-code that is *clear.*

When we read other people's source-code, we are very much guided by these "implications."  It's possible to be looking directly at a bug and not see it, for this very reason.

Comment: I agree with you.